# MP3 Player with shuffle feature

Tags: mp3-player

It's been some days since I have been searching for a suitable MP3 player.

*Why (context):* I want to get rid of smartphone/internet addiction, but can't let go of music. So, I want a standalone mp3 player.

*Why not feature phone:* I have a feature phone that I use for calling and stuff. I do not want to use that for music because it will deplete battery as listening to music is something I do for entire day. And since, I have one feature phone I do not want to buy another.

*Requirements (ranked):*

1. The maximum price should be 50 US dollars (or INR 3600 in my country).
2. Shuffle feature should be there because as per my experience it gets tiring to listen to one order of songs over and over again.

*My only good finding (that is available to buy in India):*

1. Sony NWZ-B183F: [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5TlmudMONOY) (this is without shuffle)

It seems to me I could not find one with shuffle feature (if such a player even exists) and I would appreciate any recommendation.

Comment: $50 is fairly tight; how much storage space you do need?

Comment: I currently have around 200 songs, with an average 5 MB size of each file. So, 2 GB would do the job for me.

Comment: How about a used iPod? Nanos are available used for next to nothing (even for the 16GB variant) and are still reasonably well supported by Apple.